# Both if and else statement called randomly

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I have a method which parses HTML. In there there is an if/else statement:

```
if ((NSNumber1 == NSNumber2)) {
    NSLog(@"dafuq1?");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dafuq2?");
}
```

The log is sometimes like this:

> ...:dafuq1?
>
> ...:dafuq2?

So both parts are called. But other times just one of them gets called! Why?

Btw. iOS 7.0.4, Xcode 5.0.1

And
    `(NSNumber1 == NSNumber2)` is true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605262/comparing-nsnumbers-in-objective-c

Comment: I really suggest to use **camelCase** notation.

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes both the if **and** the else branches are executed in one invocation?

Answer (score 6):

These are objects. You can't use `==` to compare equality. Use `isEqualToNumber:`.

```
if ([NSNumber1 isEqualToNumber:NSNumber2])
```

Comment: Unless you want to see if they're the same object.

Comment: @BlackRider Of course. But that isn't the case here.

Comment: @BlackRider As well, comparing `NSNumber` instances for pointer equality is a sure fire way to create baffling bugs.  On some platforms, the numbers from -2 to 11 are shared instances. On other platforms, tagged pointers means that -2^55..2^55 (or ^56?) will be effectively shared instances (though they aren't actually backed by allocations at all).