# Counting inversions in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm new to Objective-C, so I'm trying to learn by implementing algorithms. I'm doing an A* search for solving the 8-puzzle problem. Before running the algorithm itself, I want to check whether the given puzzle combination is solvable. I've written this code in C++ and Swift before, but it doesn't work correctly in Objective-C for me. For this array it gives inversion count of 7, while it should be 0. Maybe I should use [NSArray objectAtIndex:] method to access elements and then convert them to integers to compare? I've tested different ways and the comparison works right. Please help me to find the bug.

```
    NSArray *test = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @0, @8];
    NSInteger inv_count = 0;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (NSInteger j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
            if (test[j] && test[i] && test[i] > test[j]) {
                inv_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"inv_count = %ld", (long)inv_count);

    if (inv_count % 2 == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Solvable.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not solvable.");
    }
```

Comment: The condition will be false when we access element 0 with test[j]. Please see this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-instance-8-puzzle-solvable/

Comment: @VolodymyrDenysov test[j] never returns 0 coz it's a pointer to an instance of NSNumber

Comment: Yeah, I ment if this algorithm would be written in another language. That commentator didn't get the algorithm right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this line of code is wrong:

```
if(test[j] && test[i] && test[i]>test[j])
```

test is an array of `NSNumber` instances, or basically it contains pointers. So to check if an element of that array is equal to zero or compare it you should get an integer value of the element:

```
if(((NSNumber*)test[j]).integerValue && ((NSNumber*)test[i]).integerValue && ((NSNumber*)test[i]).integerValue > ((NSNumber*)test[j]).integerValue)
```

Alternatively you can use `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)aNumber` method of `NSNumber`

PS: Please check [this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605262/comparing-nsnumbers-in-objective-c) .

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But why does this work:
if(test[3]>test[1])
 NSLog(@"works")

Comment: I thought when I use subscript notation, it calls the method [objectAtIndex:] which returns type id right? That's why I need conversion to NSNumber?

Comment: @VolodymyrDenysov because `id` is a pointer to any type ;) if(test[3]>test[1]) NSLog(@"works") may work if pointer of test[3] located in higher address in device memory

Comment: @VolodymyrDenysov - Re: `test[3]>test[1]`. This compares pointers, which is legal though in Objective-C you would rarely do this (you might in C). *However* you might have observed that it *appears to work* ordering some `NSNumber` objects by their *value*. This is an "accident of implementation" and if you are curious look up "tagged pointers".

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that! Thanks a lot! And one more question, can I convert straight to NSInteger like: (NSInteger)test[index] and compare? Or I should convert to the NSNumber first?

Comment: @CRD thanks for reference, I'll definitely check that!

Comment: The expression `((NSNumber*)test[j]).integerValue` is *casting* not *converting*, it is telling the compiler that `test[j]` of type `id` - meaning a reference to *any* object - is in fact a reference to an `NSNumber`. The cast is used here so that the compiler can process the `.integerValue` property reference. You *cannot* just case an `NSNumber` reference to `NSInteger` to obtain the value, such a cast would return the integer equivalent of the reference value and would not call `integerValue`.